# TIMESTAMP(6) Oracle Insert

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, relational-database, database-schema

I am generating dummy data for a database, one attribute is using `TIMESTAMP(6)`.

Can anyone give me an example of how the value looks?

Also I would like to be able to insert the date along

i.e `03/18/2012 02:35 AM`

so that it looks like

```
INSERT INTO FLIGHT VALUES (1,'London Heathrow','Miami Airport','03/18/2012 02:35 AM','04/18/2012 13:35 PM');
```

Is this possible? Thanks alot...

EDIT----

How can i get rid of the timestamp column massive space

[image: space]

Comment: I am using `TIMESTAMP(0)` but somehow the dept_time column has a massive space, see the pic above, how can i get rid of this?

Comment: Your edit asks a different question.  SO is designed to provide discrete answers to focused questions.  If you have a new issue, please ask a new question.  There's no fee for asking questions, and you're much more likely to get an answer (although I notice Justin has actually addressed your second question in his response).

Comment: Okay ill keep it in mind, however these two were kinda related, i didn't see the point in opening a new question, Thanks goes to Justin hes an ace;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Whenever you are dealing with `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` data types, you should always insert `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` values.  You should not be inserting strings and relying on implicit conversions to convert the string to a `DATE` or a `TIMESTAMP`.  You should be explicitly calling `TO_DATE` or `TO_TIMESTAMP`.  Your `INSERT` statement should also be explicitly listing the names of the columns you're inserting into.

You'd want your `INSERT` statement to look something like this

```
INSERT INTO FLIGHT( <<list of columns>> )
  VALUES (1,
         'London Heathrow',
         'Miami Airport',
         to_timestamp( '03/18/2012 02:35 AM', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI AM'),
         to_timestamp( '04/18/2012 13:35 PM', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI AM') );
```

You can adjust how SQL*Plus displays the data in a particular column by changing the format mask.  For E.g.

```
SQL> column dept_time format a30;
SQL> column arrv_time format a30;
```

will cause SQL*Plus to display both `DEPT_TIME` and `ARRV_TIME` in 30 horizontal characters (your current `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT` appears to generate 28 character strings, if you change your `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT`, you may want to change the width of the column you're asking SQL*Plus to display).

Comment: Thanks again Justin, so time stamp and date are virtually the same?

Comment: @JoseDavidGarciaLlanos - A `DATE` stores a time to the second.  A `TIMESTAMP` can store up to 9 digits of fractional seconds.  You can also declare a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` or a `TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE` that stores a time zone as well so that you can convert times from one time zone to another.

Comment: ah OK thanks, i am getting large amounts of unused space for those columns using time stamp, you can see it in the picture above. is this fixable or that's how it should be. Thanks Justin

Comment: @JoseDavidGarciaLlanos - It appears you're talking about formatting, not unused space in the database.  You can adjust how SQL*Plus displays data and I updated my answer with an example of doing that.

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look at the following example:

```
ALTER SESSION SET nls_timestamp_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';

SELECT *
FROM orders 
WHERE ordered_at 
   BETWEEN '2013-10-06 12:00:00' 
       AND '2013-10-06 16:00:00'
```